# Change display of multiple elements with querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript

I try to target class names in a HTML page with a checkbox with querySelectorAll because `getElementByID` works only with the first element. 
And `querySelectorAll` displays a nodeList. How to correct that ?

```
let salesCheckbox = document.getElementById('sales-checkbox');
let euroSalesCurrency = document.querySelectorAll('.euro-sales-currency');
let originalSalesCurrency = document.querySelectorAll('.original-sales-currency');

if (salesCheckbox) {
    salesCheckbox.addEventListener('click', saleCheckbox);
}

//Function to close thirty
function saleCheckbox() {
    euroSalesCurrency.style.display = 'none';
    originalSalesCurrency.style.display = "block";

}
```

I want to display a span when the user is checking the checkbox, and vice versa.

Comment: Please add your HTML to the question to make it a bit more focused. Not to be picky here but "querySelectorAll" does not "display" anything, it simply returns a node list.  I also do not believe that "click" of a checkbox is the appropriate event in most cases.

Comment: Why are `euroSalesCurrency` and `originalSalesCurrency` not defined in the event handler function?  Are there multiple check boxes or are they used elsewhere?

Answer (score 5):

You need to iterate over each node on the querySelectorAll.

For example:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.euro-sales-currency').forEach(x => x.style.display = 'none')
```

Comment: or just `document.querySelectorAll('.euro-sales-currency')[0]` I suspect OP has only one element like this in his HTML code

Comment: I can have 0 or 200 elements, it's a handlebar template that display available results.

Comment: @QBolgi if that's the case, you should accept this answer (and maybe edit your question adding a portion of your HTML code)